# django - return the class name of the object instance

Tags: django, django-models

I have a base model `Asset`, to which other models have inherited from like photos and videos. I created `Asset` as the base class to get all the objects of a particular user. Its working fine. But I need to know the model class name of the asset. How do I get it?

models:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "user_objects")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Like", related_name="Liked_user")
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Comment", related_name="Commented_user")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add= False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Album(Asset):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Picture(Asset):
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, null=True, blank=True, default = None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class ProfilePicture(Picture):
    pass
```

Suppose, I need to know whether the asset is of class Album or ProfilePicture? What do I do to return the class name of the asset?

**Edit:**

eg:

```
>>> r.user_objects.all()
[<Asset: Asset>, <Asset: Asset>, <Asset: Asset>, <Asset: Asset>, <Asset: Asset>]
```

What I want is get all the assets of the user, and differentiate them according to their child's class name. Like -

```
>>> r.user_objects.all()
[<Asset: Photo>, <Asset: Video>, <Asset: Photo>, <Asset: ProfilePicture>, <Asset: Video>]
```

I hope I was clear. Please kindly guide me through. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`assetInstance.__class__.__name__` should return it.

Comment: I am sorry, where do I place `assetInstance.__class__.__name__` to?

Comment: where ever you want to get the instances class name. For example you may define a method for asset class to return the instance name.

Comment: OK, I think I didn't make myself clear. Will you please check the edit and help me again. Thank you.

Comment: r.user_objects.all() will return the classname and `__unicode__` definition of any class. So when I check your code it should return smt like [<Asset: ausername>, <Asset: ausername>] or [<Album: albumTitle>, <Album: albumTitle>] or if it is a Picture [<Picture: picDescription>, <Picture: picDescription>] But you are saying that it is returning [<Asset:Asset>,<Asset:Asset>]
For asset class please put `return self.__class__.__name__` into the `__unicode___` method.If it doesnt change anything please try to replace inherited classes' `__unicode__` methods as so and please send back results here.

Comment: Hello I tried it, but it didn't change. I even replaced all the other child classed return with 'self.__class__.name__'. But it didn't change.